# Refreshing List view in Listfragment after DB update

Tags: android, android-listview

I use the same activity for save and edit purpose. I have a list view.

In List fragment I have

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(dbHelper != null){
            Item item = (Item) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SaveEditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Update_Item", item);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Now in SaveEditActivity I have

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(....);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra("Update_Item")){
            Item item = (Item) intent.getSerializableExtra("Update_Item");
            if(item != null){
                this.isEdit = true;
                this.editedItem = item;
                setItemData(item); // set the data in activity
            }
        }
}
```

Now when user clicks on save button I check for isEdit flag

```
 if(isEdit == true){
        updateItem();//update
     }else{
      saveItem(); // add
     }
 }
```

In Update method I update the item in database using `editedItem` Object

```
private void updateItem(){
      if(this.editedItem != null){
          dbHelper.updateItem(editedItem);
      }
    }
```

But my list view is not refreshed with new data.

I am using `customAdapter` which extends `BaseAdapter`.

In ListFragmet I load the data into adapter in onResume() method

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        List<Item> existingItems = dbHelper.getItemData();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), existingItems);
        if(adapter != null){
           this.setListAdapter(adapter);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now when returning from activity this method should be called and adapter should be notified of the change? Isnt that right?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of your `adapter`? Post the code for your `updateItem()`.

Comment: not sure where to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` the updateItem method is executed in saveEditActivity and ListFragment contains the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have to notify your `ListView` that the data set changed/updated so that it should refresh itself. In one of my app I used the `Observer` interface & `Observable` class to observe data changed or not. This helps me to solve the case.

The idea you can use is on every update/save the data set changed, so after doing so you should call a method named `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
/* don't be confuse with this method's name, Its a custom method. I
   used this name. You may use another like myAbcdMethod() :) */
private void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(new Boolean(true));
}
```

`notifyDataSetChanged()` is a private method, & you should implement this in your DbHelper. After every edit.save you can call this.

And in your activity you should use the following to refresh the list:

```
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        isDataChanged = (Boolean) data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (isDataChanged) {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.refresh(screenNames.toArrayList());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            isDataChanged = false;
        }
    }
```

This works in single activity app to multiple activity app.

Comment: My `DbHelper` extends `SQLiteHelper`. I can not extend `DbHelper` with `Observable` too :(

Comment: In my List Fragment I load the arraylist from database in `onResume();` Shouldn't that refresh the listview? I do call `notifyDataSetChanged()`; after `setListAdapter();`

Comment: If u r not able to extend observable from DbHelper then use another class to save/fetch data to db, which will use the DbHelper. but from ur activity u will call ur custom class's add(Object data), edit(int pk, Object data) method. for ex. add(Object data) will responsible to save data using DbHelper object. so in add(Object data) u can use notifyDataSetChanged(). Don't be confuse with the name "notifyDataSetChanged()" this is a custom method(not overridden)... It will help u to solve the problem :) all d best.

Comment: When returning from actvity to ListFragment, `onResume();` method gets executed. I have posted my `onResume();` code in question it gets the data from DB. So this time it should get updated data? Isnt that correct?

Comment: That will update the data & It will update the list view every time while  onResume() called. But is this necessary to update the list if data is not changed ?